# How do I add CSS animations when updating a value with vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue.js to render an array into a list.

Each item in the list has a numeric value, and when that value changes I would like to use an animation.

Examples of animations:

- Existing value fades out, new value fades in.
- Yellow background behind value which fades out.
- Text colour changes then fades back to original.

How can I do this?

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users">
      {{ user.name }} = {{ user.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button v-on:click="users[0].value++">Change value</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:
  {
    users:
    [
      { name: 'Barbara Dwyer', value: 14 },
      { name: 'William B Hardigan', value: 10 }
    ]
  }
})
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryxjOE

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html

Comment: I don't want to "tween" the values. I just want to indicate that the value was updated.

Comment: Use a watch? When the value changes, add an animation class potentially to your element.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? There seems to be lots of support for animating the hiding/showing of elements, but nothing to animate a value changing!

Comment: Honestly I'm not super knowledgeable about Vue animations/transitions which is why I stuck with a comment rather than an answer. There could very well be a better way.

Comment: There's plenty for animating a value changing. Search for `:key` here. Also have an answer coming your way.

Comment: @BillCriswell thanks, looking forward to it. I'm finishing for the day soon, so will review answers/comments tomorrow morning.

Comment: By "here" I meant https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html , sorry.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You'd want to use `:key` along with a `<transition>`. Here's a very basic demo.

```
<transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
  <div :key="value">
    {{ value }}
  </div>
</transition>
```

Then, as `value` changes, the `slide-fade` animation will be used. An element with the old value will use the `leave` animation and the element with the new value will use the `enter` animation.

Here's a quick demo:

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    value: 5,
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.value++
    },
    subtract() {
      this.value--
    },
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.slide-fade-enter,
.slide-fade-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
    <div :key="value">
      {{ value }}
    </div>
  </transition>
  <button @click="add">
   Add
  </button>
  <button @click="subtract">
   Subtract
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work with my array example.

Comment: I take that back... It does work! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpKpNE

Any chance you could update your answer to include the array version? Then I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: An array wouldn't changed much here. Usually, if I find myself doing things like `users[0].value++` it indicates I need a component and I should be passing that array item as a prop.

Comment: The essential part of this answer is that you must get Vuejs to create a new element - you cannot have animation without new elements.

The `:key="value"` forces the creation of a new `div` when "value" changes, by directly tying the `div` to the value.

Comment: Please note that the main point here is `:key="value` as rightly pointed out by @James; I am emphasizing this because even when I tried this out and it didn't work, I checked the [vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#ad) and the relevant section said it only supports 
`Conditional rendering (using v-if)` and `Conditional display (using v-show)`, I just zeroed my mind that it just does not work (as awesome as the vue docs are, I find that section a little confusing, giving that animations occur also on `value change`).

Comment: I know this is a pretty old answer (to an old question), but I love the solution and I implemented it in my project, but now something bothers me: can the animation be played backward if the value is decreasing?

Comment: Absolutely. `name` on `<transition>` can be a variable and you can watch `value`, when it increases, make name slide-left, decreases, slide-right.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a standard css animation with a key dependent on the changed value. In this way a new animation starts for the new element while the previous one is discarded.

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    value: 5,
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.value++
    },
    subtract() {
      this.value--
    },
    keep() {
      this.value=this.value
    },
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.mycolor {
  background-color: green;
  animation: mymove 5s;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="mycolor" :key="value">
    {{ value }}
  </div>
  <button @click="add">
   Add
  </button>
  <button @click="subtract">
   Subtract
  </button>
  <button @click="keep">
   Keep
  </button>
</div>
```